# Print only cases of Union Type

Tags: f#

I have this code and the intent is to only print cases of the Union Type `Event`:

```ml
type CustomerPromoted = { id: string; level: int }
type CustomerCreated = { id: string; companyName: string }
type Event =
  | Created of CustomerCreated
  | Promoted of CustomerPromoted

let printEvents (events: Event list) =
  events
  |> List.iter (fun event -> printfn "%A" event)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  let created = { id = "1"; companyName = "MS" }
  let promoted = { id = "1"; level = 3 }
  printEvents [ created, promoted ]
  0
```

But the line

```ml
printEvents [ created, promoted ]
```

Results in this error:

```
This expression was expected to have type 'Event' but here has type ''a * 'b'
```

How do I solve this?

I could just use `let printEvents (events)` but then I would have this signature: `'a list -> unit` and I want to have `Event list -> unit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[ created, promoted ]` is a one element list of tuples of type `CustomerCreated * CustomerPromoted`. So the first fix would be to use the list separator `;` instead of the tuple separator `,`. `[ created; promoted ]`

Second fix is to note that discriminated unions aren't aliases. `Created` is of type `Event` that contains data of the type `CustomerCreated`. So changing `let created = { id = "1"; companyName = "MS" }` to `let created = Created { id = "1"; companyName = "MS" }` would create the type you want.